# php - How to keep image buttons state after refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session, post

I am having a problem keeping the state of some image buttons after refresh or log out. I have a favourite button on each article on page that a user can click to favourite it. I use the following jquery function to send the unique id of the post to a mysql table:

```
$('.faver').on('click',function() {

var articleId = $(this).closest('.row').attr('id');

  $.ajax(
    {
    url: "favscript/addremove",
    method: "POST",
    data: { favourite: articleId },
    success: function() 
    {  
        alert(<?php echo $favid ?>);
     }                  

  });

});
```

then in the recieving php file i get the session variable like this:

```
 session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) AND isset($_POST['favourite'])){

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);

$_SESSION['favourite'] = $_POST['favourite']; 

$favid = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['favourite']);
```

and then I insert values into mysql table like so:

```
// Firstly, check if article is favourite or not

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user=$user AND favid=$favid");
$matches = mysql_num_rows($query);

// If it is not favourited, add as favourite

if($matches == '0'){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid) VALUES ('$user', '$favid')");


}

// Instead, if it is favourited, then remove from favourites

if($matches != '0'){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user=$user AND favid=$favid");


}

}
```

Now all of the above is working but my problem is that I can't seem to figure out a way for each button to remember its state once the user refreshes or logs out. if I set $favid to $_SESSION['favourite'] it will just set the button state the same for all buttons after refresh.

this is how i check what the button state should be:

```
 <!--Favourite Button-->
    <div id="favouritediv"> 

        <?php 

        $user = $_SESSION['id'];
        $favid = $_SESSION['favourite'];  //  <- problem here

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user=$user AND favid=$favid");

    $matches = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($matches == 0){
        ?>

        <img id="button" class="faver fave0 tog" src= "favscript/images/0.jpg" onclick="" width="54" height="49">


        <?php
        }

        if ($matches == 1) {
        ?>

        <img id="button" class="faver fave0 tog" src= "favscript/images/1.jpg" onclick="" width="54" height="49">


        <?php
        }
         ?>

    </div>  
        <!--Favourite Button END-->
```

if i set $favid to the id of the article directly like: $favid = 3; it will work perfect but I can't get my head around how to do it properly with a $session variable or something that will get the article id for each button separately and only effect each button by itself.

I hope this makes sense, I am new to php and any help on how I should do this will be much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Session gets deleted after user refreshed page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want sessions even after user logged out , simply Store login activities in separate table. like columns User ID and Session IDs. finally get the last row of the activity table.

Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be to fetch all the favids for a user:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT favid FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user=$user");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $allFavIds[] = $row['favid'];
}
```

Now using $allFavIds array you can check for each button if its "favid" exists in this array.

```
<img id="button" class="faver fave0 tog" src="favscript/images/<?php echo in_array($individualFavId, $allFavIds) ? '1.jpg' : '0.jpg' ; ?>" onclick="" width="54" height="49">
```

Of-course the $individualFavId will be replaced by your individual favids.

Sample Code:

```
<img id="button" class="faver fave0 tog" src="favscript/images/<?php echo in_array(3, $allFavIds) ? '1.jpg' : '0.jpg' ; ?>" onclick="" width="54" height="49">
```